# ¿Como configurar archivo .env con node/express para servidor Heroku?

Tags: nodejs, express

En mi archivo **.env** puse los datos de coneccion a la base de datos, Pero cuando abro mi **app** desde **heroku**, no muestra los datos que tengo en la base de datos.

Aca les muestro los archivos:

**archivo .env**

```js
DB_USER=ohcmjxyayauyay
DB_HOST=xxx-xx-xx-xx-87.compute-1.amazonaws.com
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DB_NAME=d6mtxxxxxxxx
```

Entonces en mi archivo **database.ts** para conectarme hice esto:

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg'
require('dotenv').config()

export const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    ssl: { "rejectUnauthorized": false },
    port: 5432
})
```

Aca archivo **index**

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
const path = require('path');
import { Compramp } from "./compramp";
// para variables de entorno
dotenv.config(); 

import express from "express";
var multer = require("multer");
const uuid = require("uuid");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

// importacion de las rutas
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.routes";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.routes";

// stripe para pagos online
import stripeRoutes from "./routes/stripe.routes";
import mercadopagoRoutes from "./routes/mercadopago.routes";
import provinciasRoutes from "./routes/provincias.routes";
// middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);

app.use(express.static("public"));

// Tomo el puerto del sistema operativo o el 3000
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Inicio el servidor
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("usuarios server on port:", app.get("port"));
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to my API");
});
```

y este es mi archivo **package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon dist/server.js\"",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/pg": "^7.14.5",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mercadopago": "^1.5.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "pg": "^8.4.0",
    "stripe": "^8.126.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Heroku tiene para administrar las variable de entrono, entras al proyecto desplegado --> settings --> Config Vars y le das reveal config vars y ahi pones tus variables de entorno

Comment: @Franco, cuando entre a settings para crear las variables de entorno en heroku, las tengo que agregar una por una? por ejemplo, agrego una variable DB_USER, y le pongo el usuario, despues DB_HOST y le pongo el host y asi con todas?

Comment: si introduce al menos, 15 caracteres

Comment: gracias @Franco! configure las variables de entorno en Heroku y funciona.